# Different menu on different category need advice

Tags: menus

Good day. I have some difficulties these days and i am a new at wordpress. I have task where I need to create different menu's on different category's, I had read a lot about it but still have some questions.  I have created 8 category's with subcategories, and also 8 menu's including my subcategory's. In my template “html5blank-stable”  category.php  I am using this code down bellow

```
$this_category = get_category($cat); 
if (is_category( '2' ) || $this_category->category_parent == 2) { 
wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu_class' => 'menu','menu' => 'Visuomenei') );
}elseif (is_category( '16' ) || $this_category->category_parent == 16) { 
wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'menu' => 'Studentams') );
}elseif (is_category( '27' ) || $this_category->category_parent == 27) { 
wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'menu' => 'Personalui') );
}elseif (is_category( '54' ) || $this_category->category_parent == 54) { 
wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'menu' => 'Kontaktai') );
}elseif (is_category( '63' ) || $this_category->category_parent == 63) { 
wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'menu' => 'Kolegija') );
}
```

And this code works for me, but the problem is I am not sure this is good way doing it because I can't find much information maybe there are more easy methods. Any tip would be grateful.
P.S sorry for english, but I hope someone understand my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good way, Mardov. Another way is to specify the subcategory id in the `in_category` array which is easier method.

For example:

```
if (in_category( array( 2, 4, 5 ) ) { // 2, 4 & 5 can be a category or a subcategory
  wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu_class' => 'menu','menu' => 'Visuomenei') );
}
```

You may find it difficult to find the IDs of the categories, so install this plugin to [RevealIDs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/reveal-ids-for-wp-admin-25/)

Comment: Thank you for reply! now i feel more easier when i know it is right way.Your method works great.

Comment: Glad you liked it, Mardov! :) There are situations in WordPress where you have many solutions to a problem but finding the easier one maybe time consuming.